Page Number is too close to text
The Page Number is too close to the text if the whole page is full of text. I want my page number to stay at the same position it is now, but there should be more space between the page number and the text above.

My packages/commands, which I could find and im sorry for the german notes (this is probably too much, but those are all of my packages/commands. i just want to be sure there are no side effect):
 \documentclass[
   12pt, % Schriftgröße
   DIV=calc,
   ngerman, % für Umlaute, Silbentrennung etc.
   a4paper, % Papierformat
   oneside, % einseitiges Dokument
   titlepage, % es wird eine Titelseite verwendet
   parskip=half, % Abstand zwischen Absätzen (halbe Zeile)
   listof=totoc, % Verzeichnisse im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
   bibliography=totoc, % Literaturverzeichnis im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
   index=totoc, % Index im Inhaltsverzeichnis aufführen
   final, % Status des Dokuments (final/draft)
   numbers=noenddot,
]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\headsep}{30pt} % Abstand Kopfzeile Textkörper

% Pakete einbinden
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=40mm,right=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliographie.bib} % Bibliographie-Dateien hinzufügen
\addbibresource{Bibliographie_Citavi.bib}
\usepackage{placeins} % Für floatbarrier
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[
automark, % Kapitelangaben in Kopfzeile automatisch erstellen
headsepline, % Trennlinie unter Kopfzeile
ilines % Trennlinie linksbündig ausrichten
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% Fortlaufendes Durchnummerieren der Fußnoten
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Zähler für Abbildungen innerhalb der Sektionen
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}

% Fußnoten bei jeder Seite neu beginnen
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}

% Zeilenabstand 1,5 Zeilen
\onehalfspacing

% Kopf- und Fußzeilen
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

% Schriftform der Kopfzeile
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont}

% Kopfzeile
\ihead{\textit{\headmark}}
\chead{} 
\ohead{}

% Kopfzeilenhöhe
\setlength{\headheight}{21mm}
\setlength{\footheight}{21mm}


% Fußzeile
\ifoot{}
\cfoot{}
\ofoot{\pagemark}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

 
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\clearpage

% 1,5-facher Zeilenabstand
\onehalfspacing

% Text-Inhalt einfügen
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% Beispieltext mit Lorem Ipsum
\lipsum[21-25] % Lorem Ipsum Text als Platzhalter

\end{document}


you have shown a fragment of code but it's hard to comment on it as you have shown no definitions, by default latex does not have a \footheight length, or a \pagemark command

whatever defines \footheight you probably shouldn't use it as well as geometry. (but this is a guess. if it is the height of the ogre's foot in your picture of Jack and the Beanstalk, you can obviously ignore this comment.)

Probably unrelated, but the ngerman package is deprecated. Do \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} instead.

When I compile your code on my system (MacTeX2024, with all updates applied), I am unable to replicate the issue you say you wish to fix.

what @Mico said. I don't get 6 pages, but the first page number is not up against the text when I compile your code - it looks not at all like the image you show. possibly off-topic, but you're having typearea calculate page layout. you're then loading geometry to override it. you can use geometry with koma classes, if necessary, but it doesn't make much sense to first calculate the layout and then undo it all. also, the log has a bunch of info/warning messages you should probably pay at least some attention to e.g. about chngctr, bookmark etc.

There's no advantage in running setup commands, such as \onehalfspacing, twice. To the contrary, the resulting clutter of redundant commands makes it a lot more tedious to debug anything.

Thanks for all the help! The problem only occurs on pages that are very full; it's not an issue on most pages, just a few. I'm using a template provided by my university, but now I'm unsure why it includes those seemingly unnecessary and contradictory commands/packages.
@Mico, you're right. My MWE is somehow different from my original project (even the font isn't the same), but I can't figure out what the difference is between them. Regarding the error messages: there aren't any in my Overleaf log (there are only biblatex, missing references and "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)....")

My MWE is a combination of three different files, without including any of the other content files (which don't seem to contain any additional packages/commands). I'm not sure if this is contributing to some of the confusion caused by the template.

By the \setlength commands, you are taking the room and flexibility from LaTeX
Play with the values in:
% Kopfzeilenhöhe
\setlength{\headheight}{0mm}%value
\setlength{\footheight}{0mm}%value

or just delete
% Kopfzeilenhöhe
\setlength{\headheight}{21mm}
\setlength{\footheight}{21mm}

if they are not really needed.

er ... no. setting \headheight to 0mm will cause bad boxes if the document uses headers. changing \footheight may or may not do anything, depending on if and how it is defined.

@cfr  It does something....   In the given example, there are no badboxes in my logs , wether with or without the \headheight or \ footheight settings. Maybe Prometheus should explain, if they are  really needed.

@cfr "you can't have tested"?  If I copy and paste OP's code, the page "1" numeral is within \baselineskip or so of the text.  If I follow MBE's suggestions, it isn't (although 0mm causes 3 warnings about insufficient height and an overfull vbox).  It may be a bad answer, but it is entirely testable.  OTOH, I wouldn't hold my breathe for Prometheus to explain, given how the question's comments have gone.

I did not suggest to set the values to 0, but to vary them. By setting the values to 0, the badboxes do appear, by deleting the settings of the \setlength\headhight and \footheight, they do not. But why this occurs, I do not know.

In fact, the example of prometheus is too complex. Who would find out the problem, if over 27 packages are used?

@Teepeemm I just meant that nobody could reproduce the problem, so I don't see how anybody could test anything. but I've deleted the comment anyhow.

It is usually not a good idea to first set the page geometries (margins resp. size of text area) using package geometry and afterwards breaking these setting by manual changes of page geometry lengths. In your case, your
\setlength{\headheight}{21mm}

does not only change the height of the page header inside the top margin. Instead it moves down the whole page content, by increasing the height of the page header. So, e.g., the bottom setting is no longer valid.
Additionally the
\setlength{\footheight}{21mm}

increases the height of the foot and because scrlayer-scrpage usually top aligns the foot, this moves the single line number upwards. So the best solution is (as MBE already told) to remove these two lines. Then you'd get:

which should be a proper placement for the page number. If you still want to move the number, you can use geometry option footskip, e.g.
\usepackage[left=40mm,right=20mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm,footskip=10mm]{geometry}

to get

If you really want to increase the head height, you should use geometry option headheight.
BTW:

Because you are using \onehalfspacing I would also recommend scrlayer-scrpage option singlespacing.
For better cooperation of KOMA-Script and geometry I also would recommend option usegeometry.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} is not needed for more than a decade. So if you really need it, you should update your TeX distribution.
\usepackage{textcomp} also should not be needed any longer.
Package here is only a compatibility wrapper for package float.
Package chngcntr is not needed for several years.
Loading packages more than once is not recommended.
\pagestle{scrheadings} is already the default after loading package scrlayer-scrpage.
Redefinition of \headfont is deprecated. You should use \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{} instead.
Instead of using \ihead{\textit{…}} you should use \ihead{…} and \setkomafont{pagehead}{\itshape}.
\pagenumbering{gobble} immediately before \pagenumbering{Roman} is useless.
Options a4paper and oneside are defaults with scrartcl.
\setlength{\headsep}{30pt} before setting up the page geometry using package geometry is useless. If you want to change the distance of the page header to the body see the geometry user manual.

